# TFS 2010 wants to branch / merge every file

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

We just upgraded to TFS 2010. We created a development branch for each project. If changes are made in Branch1 and then Branch1 is merged back into the baseline, it merges every file instead of just the changed files.

Subsequent changes to files in Branch1 and then merging to the baseline result in only those changes being merged (which is what we want) *unless* changes from Branch2 were merged in between the first and second merge of Branch1, then every file merges again (which we don't want).

How can we make it so only changed files get merged everytime?

Comment: That really shouldn't be happening.  If you look at the changeset history, what are the changes that are happening?  Do a diff between the versions and see what it says.  The only thing that immediately comes to mind is that somehow the file encoding is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem was that we had created the development branches, then deleted them, then recreated them. We ran into a problem similar to this in the past where a file was deleted, then a new file was added with the same name. The fix for the past problem was to do a baseless merge. Rather than go through that we decided to just delete the development branches and rebranch them with different names.

Comment: Oh yeah.  Be careful with deletes.  They don't do what you think they do.  If you branch incorrectly, you need to to a `TF.EXE destroy` on the branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to merge specific change sets instead of upto the latest change sets. That way you can even control which changes get merged into other branches instead of all changes being merged at the same time.

Also, when there are no changes, the automerge should take care of the files without creating any problems. What specific problems are you facing?